# Right approach to enriching JSON data from a Web API call before sending the ActionResult back in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC 5(MVC and Web API in general), I'm looking for a good approach to creating my viewmodel in the MVC controller based on data I get back from making a Web API call.

The web api call method returns data like this

```
public ActionResult GetConfigTable([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var emp = new fpECMEntities();

        IQueryable<Models.MyTable> empSecurity = emp.MyTable;
        DataSourceResult result = empSecurity.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

my views controller method looks like this

```
 public ActionResult Config_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var configTable = Json(MySolution.API.Controllers.HomeController.GetConfigTable());

        // fill in the code

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Where the API is a separate project within the solution which keeps all the Models and acts as a DAL. So, here I need to add additional columns to the JSON data I get back from API before I send it off to the Grid in the view.

My questions is

1. Is this the right approach to create the viewmodel in my MVC controller by massaging the data here
2. Is it better to create a method within the API that generates all the data required for my ViewModel?
3. If #1 is ok, then what is the code to massage the data? do I have to deserialize the JSON data into Dataset and then add columns and return it as JSON again?

Any and all advice is greatly appreciated. BTW, I'm using the Kendo UI grid at the client, the types DataSourceRequest and DataSourceResult are from Kendo.UI.DataSourceRequest library.

Thanks